# Implementing simple allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, free, allocator

As a part of vector implementation I have to implement an allocator using functions `malloc()` and `free()` given the below interface:

class `Allocator` manages memory for class vector:

```
template<class T>
class Allocator {
public:
    // function members
    T* allocate(int n);
    void deallocate(T* p, int n);

    void construct(T* p, const T& v);
    void destroy(T* p);
};
```

class `Allocator` member implementations:

```
/*
    Function: allocate()
    Use: allocator_object.allocator(num_of_elements) 

    Implicit in vector_base constructor.
    It wraps malloc(); Throws bad_alloc
    if allocation unsuccessful.
*/
template <class T>
T* Allocator<T>::allocate(int n) {
    try {
        std::auto_ptr<T> mem_ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(malloc(n * sizeof(T)));
    } catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::cerr <<"bad_alloc caught: "<< e.what() <<'\n';
        throw;
    }
    return mem_ptr.release();
}

/*
    Function: deallocate()
    Use: allocator_object.deallocate(mem_ptr, redundant_par);

    Implicit in base_vector destructor.
    It returns memory to free store. 
    First argument is the pointer returned by malloc(). 
*/
template <class T>
void Allocator<T>::deallocate(T* mem_ptr, int n) {
    free(mem_ptr);
}

/*
    Function: construct()
    Use: allocator_object.construct(elem_ptr[i], value)

    Implicit in vector_base constructor
    and all modifying members of vector.
    It assigns the value passed as second
    argument to the element with address
    held by the pointer passed as a first 
    argument.
*/
template <class T>
void Allocator<T>::construct(T* p, const T& v = T()) {
    *p = v;
}

/*
    Function: destroy()
    Use: allocator_object.destroy(elem_ptr[i]); 

    Implicitly in vector members: reserve(), resize();
    It assigns type default value to the element
    with address held by the pointer passed as argument.
*/
template <class T>
void Allocator<T>::destroy(T* p) {
    *p = T(); // ? not sure if right 
}
```

**How to check for possible bad allocations** from `malloc()` in function `allocate()`<sup>1</sup>, is the current method correct?

### Edit:

Is the implementation of function `destroy()` correct<sup>2</sup>, **could you give me an example of correct implementation**?

There is an additional argument, `n`, in function `deallocate()` which I can't figure out how(what for) to use.

---

<sup>1. I know I'm using a deprecated `std::auto_ptr`, <strike>just following the book recommendations</strike> wrongly trying to get rid of the pointer in case of bad allocation.</sup>

<sup>2. I've read [the documentation for function `destroy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/destroy/), but considering the fact that the allocated memory is one contiguous chunk that is `free()`d by passing the pointer returned by `malloc()`, the only reasonable *object destruction* is the assignment of a default value.</sup>

Comment: Book recommendation? `auto_ptr` calls `delete` not `free`. If the book really says that, consider the entire book dubious. Such a serious mistake betrays a significant lack of understanding.

Comment: That doesn't matter: `auto_ptr` never called `free`. That said, I don't get what `auto_ptr` is doing there at all. It appears to be cargo-culty.

Comment: @MSalters I've edited to describe my intention of the use of `auto_ptr`. The book edition (2009) implies only `<memory>` members before _C++11_, i.e.` auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::bad_alloc` isn't magically generated. `malloc` fails by returning `nullptr` and there's nothing which would convert that into an exception. You call `malloc`, so you must check the return value manually.

`destroy` is wrong for the same reason as `construct` is wrong: They're a pair of functions that turn raw memory into an object and back. The normal way to do so is by *placement new* and direct invocation of the destructor. You're just calling the assignment operator there, which doesn't affect the objects lifetime at all.

Comment: This allocator is for vector which is built on top of an array, i.e. the allocator dynamically changes the size of the array. I'm having difficulties understanding what does it mean to  call a destructor/constructor on the element of an array? Could you please give me an implementation example for on of the two functions in question.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: Nothing special about being part of an array, it's the basic `new(p) T` / `p->~T()`  stuff.

Comment: I think I got what you are saying: the array will hold an address to dynamically allocated object, which is created by `new(p) T` and destroyed by `p->~T()`, right?

Comment: I know `new T` when default constructing and `new T(param)` otherwise. Could you clarify the syntax: `new(p) T`?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: `(p)`  here is an argument to `new` and means that there's already memory allocated.

Comment: is it equivalent to `p = new T;`?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: Not at all. `p = new T` combines memory allocation and object creation. p receives the new address (output). In `new (p) T`, p is an input. And from context, we know `p` comes indirectly from `.allocate(int n)`.

Comment: Thank you for you time and help, but could you clearly state the syntax: or add a link to an explanation, what is `T`, what is the result of : `new (p) T` and what is happening when executed?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: `T` is the template parameter which you introduced, the type of object to create. `new(p) T` creates a default-created `T` object in allocated but unused memory at address `p`.

Comment: So `new(p) T` means: _"create an object `T` at memory location indicted by the address held in the pointer `p`."_